# What to do when one's server is being scanned very agressively

Tags: web-application, webserver

I can see that my application, which is on several virtual instances, is being scanned; I guess the attackers are in "recon mode."

**What I know:**

I understand that we can block *dirbuster*, and other scanners in `.htaccess`, 
*(However, you could just change the name of the `user agent` and then this would not be suitable solution anymore)*

I have also looked at a `WAF`, however this would require me to put some new features on hold, and re-work the development plan.

**My question:**

Is it possible that we could block these scans on a deeper level, so they can't do this? What would you guys do?

Comment: What do you mean by "being scanned"? Are they hitting non-existing directories looking for something like Wordpress or did you happen to place your CMS in the /admin/ directory? Something along those lines? How can you tell you're being "scanned"?

Comment: I think you are looking for fail2ban. Blocks clients temporarily if they do to many connections in a given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt for protection from a scrubbing service by placing your applications behind a packet scrubbing service like Akamai or CloudFlare. These CDN's will take the hit for you normally before it reaches you.